# Python Crashing When Tearing Down Main Window

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I'm getting this error when running the below code. I understand that it's failing because of the teardown of the main window not being on the main thread. Just not totally sure how to change it.

> Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread

```
def download(url, filename):
root = progressbar = quit_id = None
ready = Event()

def reporthook(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
    nonlocal quit_id
    if blocknum == 0:  # started downloading
        def guiloop():
            nonlocal root, progressbar
            root = Tk()
            root.withdraw()  # hide
            progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=400)
            progressbar.grid()
            # show progress bar if the download takes more than .5 seconds
            root.after(500, root.deiconify)
            ready.set()  # gui is ready
            root.mainloop()

        Thread(target=guiloop).start()
    ready.wait(1)  # wait until gui is ready
    percent = blocknum * blocksize * 1e2 / totalsize  # assume totalsize > 0
    if quit_id is None:
        root.title('%%%.0f %s' % (percent, filename,))
        progressbar['value'] = percent  # report progress
        if percent >= 100:  # finishing download
            quit_id = root.after(0, root.destroy)  # close GUI
return urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook)
```

Comment: GOT EM I added "quit_id = root.after(0, root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing())) # close GUI" with a root.destroy() funcation

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from threading import Event, Thread
from tkinter import Tk, ttk
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

def download(url, filename):
    root = progressbar = quit_id = None
    ready = Event()
```

> def on_closing():
>               root.destroy()

```
    def reporthook(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
        nonlocal quit_id
        if blocknum == 0: # started downloading
            def guiloop():
                nonlocal root, progressbar
                root = Tk()
                root.withdraw()  # hide
                progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=400)
                progressbar.grid()

                # show progress bar if the download takes more than .5 seconds
                root.after(500, root.deiconify)
                ready.set() # gui is ready
                root.mainloop()
            Thread(target=guiloop).start()
        ready.wait(1) # wait until gui is ready
        percent = blocknum * blocksize * 1e2 / totalsize # assume totalsize > 0
        if quit_id is None:
            root.title('%%%.0f %s' % (percent, filename,))
            progressbar['value'] = percent # report progress
            if percent >= 100:  # finishing download
```

> quit_id = root.after(0, root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",
>   on_closing())) # close GUI

```
    return urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook)
```